# Cotangent exact sequence is left exact for regular immersions of a curve which is smooth on a dense open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a scheme over a field $k$, and let $i : X\rightarrow Y$ be a regular closed immersion such that $X$ is a curve smooth over $k$ on a dense open. Let $I$ be the sheaf of ideals of $i$. If We have the canonical exact sequence
$$I/I^2\rightarrow i^*\Omega^1_{Y/k}\rightarrow\Omega^1_{X/k}\rightarrow 0$$
Is this sequence also left exact as well?

I believe the answer is yes: Since the sequence is left exact when restricted to the dense open smooth locus, the kernel of $I/I^2\rightarrow i^*\Omega^1_{Y/k}$ is supported on a finite set of points, and hence is a torsion sheaf, but $I/I^2$ is locally free (since $i$ is a regular immersion), and hence cannot contain any nontrivial torsion subsheaves.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is true, although you should require that $Y$ is smooth (your title does, your question text does not).

Comment: @KReiser Why is it necessary to require $Y$ smooth? Isn't the local freeness of $I/I^2$ enough?

Comment: I heard this as a remark of Kollar, so presumably it's true or I misremembered a hypothesis or two. In the case that $X$ is smooth over $k$, then it is true that the sequence is exact on the left by restricting to an affine open and noting the vanishing of the Andre-Quillen cohomology for $X/k$. (There are further alterations to be made to your question, though - you still have a mismatch between the title and body about the smoothness of $Y$, and it is not true that the kernel is supported on a finite set of points in general, just that it must be supported on a proper closed subvariety.) ...

Comment: @KReiser Ahhh, of course. Good point. I had tacitly assumed that $X$ was a curve (which is the case I was interested in), in which case I do believe there is the kernel is supported on a finite set.